# string -- x y in REGEX

Tags: regex

Quick question. I have this string

`string -- x y`

I manage to get the constants down

`/(string) (--) (X) (Y)/`

my problem is x y. X and Y can be between 1-999 there's no leading zeros so no need to check on that.

Comment: Maybe, It can be useful to have a better title. Something like "Leading zeros in numeric string" or "Numeric range in string"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string -- ([1-9]\d{0,2}) ([1-9]\d{0,2})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YL1Q0onlSHJrRLsl)

**[Description](https://regex101.com/r/fF8lX9/1)**

```
string --  matches the characters string --  literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing group ([1-9]\d{0,2})
    [1-9] match a single character present in the list below
        1-9 a single character in the range between 1 and 9
    \d{0,2} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {0,2} Between 0 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
      matches the character   literally
2nd Capturing group ([1-9]\d{0,2})
    [1-9] match a single character present in the list below
        1-9 a single character in the range between 1 and 9
    \d{0,2} match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: {0,2} Between 0 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
```

**Examples**

```
string -- 1 999 //matches
string -- 10 02 //does not match
string -- 011 222 //does not match
string -- 111 222 //matches
string -- 41 2 //matches
string -- 999 1 //matches
string -- 1 1 //matches
```

Comment: This won’t match 999.

Comment: @bfontaine yes yes it will, please click the Debuggex Demo.  It will prove that it matches 999

Comment: Ha sorry didn’t see the leading `[1-9]`.

Comment: `10` is not a valid number?  Your regex doesn't include any zeros not just leading zeros!

Comment: @karakfa incorrect..please use the debuggex demo to show it does.  The reason 10 02 doesn't work is because 02 is in the line..which is...a leading zero.

Comment: Guys please read the RegEx. Im not an expert but still know this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could express avoidance of leading zeroes (and zeroes) using a negative look ahead:

```
/(string) (--)(?!.* 0) (\d{1,3}) (\d{1,3})
```

Answer (score 0):

For the number portion you should be checking  `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}`.  Otherwise you'll miss valid numbers such as `10` and `101`.

Comment: Yes, the same, I guess old eyes won't notice the `\d` there.